# List Duplicates 3 Times, WHY?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Once I add the customers, sales, and thread_sold into the list, it duplicates them 3 times. WHY?

Everything works right up until the last for loop, which should work, but doesn't.

I've tried to use many compilers, online and offline like Visual Studio Code. But, nothing seems to want to display in the correct way. What I don't understand is how if I never use a loop to repeat it does it do it 4 times?

```
daily_sales = \
"""Edith Mcbride   ;,;$1.21   ;,;   white ;,; 
09/15/17   ,Herbert Tran   ;,;   $7.29;,; 
white&blue;,;   09/15/17 ,Paul Clarke ;,;$12.52 
;,;   white&blue ;,; 09/15/17 ,Lucille Caldwell   
;,;   $5.13   ;,; white   ;,; 09/15/17,
Eduardo George   ;,;$20.39;,; white&yellow 
;,;09/15/17   ,   Danny Mclaughlin;,;$30.82;,;   
purple ;,;09/15/17 ,Stacy Vargas;,; $1.85   ;,; 
purple&yellow ;,;09/15/17,   Shaun Brock;,; 
$17.98;,;purple&yellow ;,; 09/15/17 , 
Erick Harper ;,;$17.41;,; blue ;,; 09/15/17, 
Michelle Howell ;,;$28.59;,; blue;,;   09/15/17   , 
Carroll Boyd;,; $14.51;,;   purple&blue   ;,;   
09/15/17   , Teresa Carter   ;,; $19.64 ;,; 
white;,;09/15/17   ,   Jacob Kennedy ;,; $11.40   
;,; white&red   ;,; 09/15/17, Craig Chambers;,; 
$8.79 ;,; white&blue&red   ;,;09/15/17   , Peggy Bell;,; $8.65 ;,;blue   ;,; 09/15/17,   Kenneth Cunningham ;,;   $10.53;,;   green&blue   ;,; 
09/15/17   ,   Marvin Morgan;,;   $16.49;,; 
green&blue&red   ;,;   09/15/17 ,Marjorie Russell 
;,; $6.55 ;,;   green&blue&red;,;   09/15/17 ,
Israel Cummings;,;   $11.86   ;,;black;,;  
09/15/17,   June Doyle   ;,;   $22.29 ;,;  
black&yellow ;,;09/15/17 , Jaime Buchanan   ;,;   
$8.35;,;   white&black&yellow   ;,;   09/15/17,   
Rhonda Farmer;,;$2.91 ;,;   white&black&yellow   
;,;09/15/17, Darren Mckenzie ;,;$22.94;,;green 
;,;09/15/17,Rufus Malone;,;$4.70   ;,; green&yellow 
;,; 09/15/17   ,Hubert Miles;,;   $3.59   
;,;green&yellow&blue;,;   09/15/17   , Joseph Bridges  ;,;$5.66   ;,; green&yellow&purple&blue 
;,;   09/15/17 , Sergio Murphy   ;,;$17.51   ;,;   
black   ;,;   09/15/17 , Audrey Ferguson ;,; 
$5.54;,;black&blue   ;,;09/15/17 ,Edna Williams ;,; 
$17.13;,; black&blue;,;   09/15/17,   Randy Fleming;,;   $21.13 ;,;black ;,;09/15/17 ,Elisa Hart;,; $0.35   ;,; black&purple;,;   09/15/17   ,
Ernesto Hunt ;,; $13.91   ;,;   black&purple ;,;   
09/15/17,   Shannon Chavez   ;,;$19.26   ;,; 
yellow;,; 09/15/17   , Sammy Cain;,; $5.45;,;   
yellow&red ;,;09/15/17 ,   Steven Reeves ;,;$5.50   
;,;   yellow;,;   09/15/17, Ruben Jones   ;,; 
$14.56 ;,;   yellow&blue;,;09/15/17 , Essie Hansen;,;   $7.33   ;,;   yellow&blue&red
;,; 09/15/17   ,   Rene Hardy   ;,; $20.22   ;,; 
black ;,;   09/15/17 ,   Lucy Snyder   ;,; $8.67   
;,;black&red  ;,; 09/15/17 ,Dallas Obrien ;,;   
$8.31;,;   black&red ;,;   09/15/17,   Stacey Payne 
;,;   $15.70   ;,;   white&black&red ;,;09/15/17   
,   Tanya Cox   ;,;   $6.74   ;,;yellow   ;,; 
09/15/17 , Melody Moran ;,;   $30.84   
;,;yellow&black;,;   09/15/17 , Louise Becker   ;,; 
$12.31 ;,; green&yellow&black;,;   09/15/17 ,
Ryan Webster;,;$2.94 ;,; yellow ;,; 09/15/17 
,Justin Blake ;,; $22.46   ;,;white&yellow ;,;   
09/15/17,   Beverly Baldwin ;,;   $6.60;,;   
white&yellow&black ;,;09/15/17   ,   Dale Brady   
;,;   $6.27 ;,; yellow   ;,;09/15/17 ,Guadalupe Potter ;,;$21.12   ;,; yellow;,; 09/15/17   , 
Desiree Butler ;,;$2.10   ;,;white;,; 09/15/17  
,Sonja Barnett ;,; $14.22 ;,;white&black;,;   
09/15/17, Angelica Garza;,;$11.60;,;white&black   
;,;   09/15/17   ,   Jamie Welch   ;,; $25.27   ;,; 
white&black&red ;,;09/15/17   ,   Rex Hudson   
;,;$8.26;,;   purple;,; 09/15/17 ,   Nadine Gibbs 
;,;   $30.80 ;,;   purple&yellow   ;,; 09/15/17   , 
Hannah Pratt;,;   $22.61   ;,;   purple&yellow   
;,;09/15/17,Gayle Richards;,;$22.19 ;,; 
green&purple&yellow ;,;09/15/17   ,Stanley Holland 
;,; $7.47   ;,; red ;,; 09/15/17 , Anna Dean;,;$5.49 ;,; yellow&red ;,;   09/15/17   ,
Terrance Saunders ;,;   $23.70  ;,;green&yellow&red 
;,; 09/15/17 ,   Brandi Zimmerman ;,; $26.66 ;,; 
red   ;,;09/15/17 ,Guadalupe Freeman ;,; $25.95;,; 
green&red ;,;   09/15/17   ,Irving Patterson 
;,;$19.55 ;,; green&white&red ;,;   09/15/17 ,Karl Ross;,;   $15.68;,;   white ;,;   09/15/17 , Brandy Cortez ;,;$23.57;,;   white&red   ;,;09/15/17, 
Mamie Riley   ;,;$29.32;,; purple;,;09/15/17 ,Mike Thornton   ;,; $26.44 ;,;   purple   ;,; 09/15/17, 
Jamie Vaughn   ;,; $17.24;,;green ;,; 09/15/17   , 
Noah Day ;,;   $8.49   ;,;green   ;,;09/15/17   
,Josephine Keller ;,;$13.10 ;,;green;,;   09/15/17 ,   Tracey Wolfe;,;$20.39 ;,; red   ;,; 09/15/17 ,
Ignacio Parks;,;$14.70   ;,; white&red ;,;09/15/17 
, Beatrice Newman ;,;$22.45   ;,;white&purple&red 
;,;   09/15/17, Andre Norris   ;,;   $28.46   ;,;   
red;,;   09/15/17 ,   Albert Lewis ;,; $23.89;,;   
black&red;,; 09/15/17,   Javier Bailey   ;,;   
$24.49   ;,; black&red ;,; 09/15/17   , Everett Lyons ;,;$1.81;,;   black&red ;,; 09/15/17 ,   
Abraham Maxwell;,; $6.81   ;,;green;,;   09/15/17   
,   Traci Craig ;,;$0.65;,; green&yellow;,; 
09/15/17 , Jeffrey Jenkins   ;,;$26.45;,; 
green&yellow&blue   ;,;   09/15/17,   Merle Wilson 
;,;   $7.69 ;,; purple;,; 09/15/17,Janis Franklin   
;,;$8.74   ;,; purple&black   ;,;09/15/17 ,  
Leonard Guerrero ;,;   $1.86   ;,;yellow  
;,;09/15/17,Lana Sanchez;,;$14.75   ;,; yellow;,;   
09/15/17   ,Donna Ball ;,; $28.10  ;,; 
yellow&blue;,;   09/15/17   , Terrell Barber   ;,; 
$9.91   ;,; green ;,;09/15/17   ,Jody Flores;,; 
$16.34 ;,; green ;,;   09/15/17,   Daryl Herrera 
;,;$27.57;,; white;,;   09/15/17   , Miguel Mcguire;,;$5.25;,; white&blue   ;,;   09/15/17 ,   
Rogelio Gonzalez;,; $9.51;,;   white&black&blue   
;,;   09/15/17   ,   Lora Hammond ;,;$20.56 ;,; 
green;,;   09/15/17,Owen Ward;,; $21.64   ;,;   
green&yellow;,;09/15/17,Malcolm Morales ;,;   
$24.99   ;,;   green&yellow&black;,; 09/15/17 ,   
Eric Mcdaniel ;,;$29.70;,; green ;,; 09/15/17 
,Madeline Estrada;,;   $15.52;,;green;,;   09/15/17 
, Leticia Manning;,;$15.70 ;,; green&purple;,; 
09/15/17 ,   Mario Wallace ;,; $12.36 ;,;green ;,; 
09/15/17,Lewis Glover;,;   $13.66   ;,;   
green&white;,;09/15/17,   Gail Phelps   ;,;$30.52   
;,; green&white&blue   ;,; 09/15/17 , Myrtle Morris 
;,;   $22.66   ;,; green&white&blue;,;09/15/17"""

#------------------------------------------------
# Start coding below!
daily_sales_replaced = daily_sales.replace(";,;", '*')
daily_transactions = daily_sales_replaced.split(",")
#print(daily_transactions)

daily_transactions_split = []
for transaction in daily_transactions:
  daily_transactions_split.append(transaction.split("*"))
#print(daily_transactions_split)

transactions_clean = []

for transaction in daily_transactions_split:
  transaction_clean = []
  for data_point in transaction:
    transaction_clean.append(data_point.replace("\n", "").strip(" "))
    transactions_clean.append(transaction_clean)
#print(transactions_clean)

customers = []
sales = []
thread_sold = []

for transaction in transactions_clean:
  customers.append(transaction[0])
  #sales.append(transaction[1])
  #thread_sold.append(transaction[2])

print(customers)
#print(sales)
#print(thread_sold)
```

Should show all customers in the customers[], each name once. But, it shows each 4 times.

*This is a question referencing Code Academy's Python Project: Thread Shed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the block

```
for transaction in daily_transactions_split:
  transaction_clean = []
  for data_point in transaction:
    transaction_clean.append(data_point.replace("\n", "").strip(" "))
    transactions_clean.append(transaction_clean)
```

which will execute the line

```
transactions_clean.append(transaction_clean)
```

once for every `data_point` in the current `transaction`, and by `append`ing each time you get multiple instances in `transactions_clean`. You want it to execute only once per `transaction`, i.e.

```
for transaction in daily_transactions_split:
  transaction_clean = []
  for data_point in transaction:
    transaction_clean.append(data_point.replace("\n", "").strip(" "))
  transactions_clean.append(transaction_clean)
```